# Voice Recognition technology

Tags: voice-recognition

I am curious is there any voice recognition  technology in the market such that it is able to identify different people through different voice.

Basically the technology i am searching for is able to model people's voices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuance VocalPassword is one that I know of. It does exactly like you say, allows users to go through an enrolment process to create a voiceprint which that then be used to authenticate.
http://www.nuance.com/for-business/customer-service-solutions/voice-biometrics/vocalpassword/index.htm

Comment: i do hv a question. which function am i able to use in order to get voiceprint for authentication?